# mod_rewrite regex ignoring empty matches

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a section of my site that I want to browse by 4 filter criteria passed in the URL:

```
http://site/browse/a/b/c/d
```

Each of the 4 parameters should be optional.
I have this mod_rewrite rule in place:

```
RewriteRule ^browse(/([^/]*)(/([^/]*)(/([^/]*)(/([^/]*))?)?)?)? /photo.php?a=$2&b=$4&c=$6&d=$8 [L]
```

It works fine if I have all 4 parameters, or omit later parameters, but if I try and skip the first parameters I get unexpected behavior:

```
http://site/browse/1/2/3/4 = /photo.php?a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4 [correct]
http://site/browse/1/2     = /photo.php?a=1&b=2         [correct]
http://site/browse//2/3/4  = /photo.php?a=2&b=3&c=4     [unexpected]
http://site/browse////4    = /photo.php?a=4             [unexpected]
```

Rather than passing an empty string as the first match, it ignores that match entirely and treats multiple sequential slashes as if they were one and puts the parameters in the wrong variable. If I put any non-empty placeholder in the empty variable it works, but I would rather not handle it like that:

```
http://site/browse/-/-/-/4 = /photo.php?a=-&b=-&c=-&d=4 [works,not pretty]
```

How can I fix my regex so that `http://site/browse////4` gives `/photo.php?a=&b=&c=&d=4` ?

**edit**: In another experiement I found that the multiple slashes are always merged, for example `http://site/photo/browse////4` into `RewriteRule ^photo/(browse.*)` matches "browse/4" not "browse////4" as would be expected.
I guess the question should be how to stop mod_rewrite from merging sequential slashes into one?

Answer (score -1):

This seems to do the trick, at least for matching (I'm not 100% sure you're even allowed to have blank url segments in rewrite rules, but this *regex* does the right thing, anyway):

```
browse\/([^\/]*)\/?([^\/]*)\/?([^\/]*)\/?([^\/]*)
```

Try it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/eA5pT1/1)

The key mistake you made was in the way you used ?. You made whole blocks optional, so it dropped them and you got your matches out with a different indexing. My regex only makes the `/` optional, causing a zero-length capturing group for all the other variables if there's nothing there.

Comment: The behavior of regex within mod_rewrite is the unexpected part. If you try your regex within .htaccess it still gives the same behavior: `http://site/browse///c/d/e/f/g` matches $1=c, $2=d, etc. The problem centers on sequential slashes being silently ignored and treated as a single slash. I cannot replicate this behavior in other regex environments (e.g. your fiddle, or in PHP).